# Cannot use MySQL connection on the hosting

Tags: asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, web

I'm building a website and also deploying it on the hosting to test if it is working online or not, cuz the time has shown that it can work locally but when deployed by some reason it doesnt work as intended.

So after i made a small user form to let user choose from drop down menu, the drop down menu is databinded with MySQL database which is located online. So lokally everything works well and fine.

Just to clarify i use entity framework, the model is generated from the MySQL database. Connection string is saved in the web.config.

When i published it on the hosting when i go to that page with the drop down menu i get an error:

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the
>   requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>
> Source Error:   An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

Although it really strange the MySQL database is running on the same server, so it is installed on the server, also i locally copied the dll's that my website uses and uploaded them to the hosting.

Update:
The problem is solved by cooperation with the hosting provider, i found that they didn't add a permissionset for mysql database, after they did add it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in good direction, but your host should add some security permissions for you to use mysql connector this way - check [MySql.Data in GAC, still SecurityException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792920/mysql-data-in-gac-still-securityexception)

Answer (score 1):

The exception message says it all:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not
>   be installed.

What data provider are you using? A guess is the MySQL Connector/.NET.

You need to install both the MySQL server software itself and the .NET provider for MySQL on your server. Even though you've installed the server, the provider is still missing on the server.

Comment: Nope that is not the issue, im deploying website on the existing hosting which i pay for, and normally everything is installed there. MySQL etc etc .... and i dont have that much access to install there anything.

Comment: connector/net now requires MySqlClientPermission also